# A problem on conituous first derivative function

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $g\in C^1 [a,b]$. Prove that for all $\epsilon > 0$, there is $\delta > 0$ such that $|{g'(c)} - {{g(d)-g(c)} \over {d-c}} |{< \epsilon }$ for all points $c,d \in [a,b]$ with $0 <|d-c|< \delta$

First, I don't know what  $|{g'(c)} - {{g(d)-g(c)} \over {d-c}}|$ mean. Does $g\in C^1 [a,b]$ imply, $g'(c)$ is zero? Also how does $g'(c) = \lim_{d\rightarrow c}{{g(d)-g(c)} \over {d-c}}$ apply to the question? 
To prove the statement in the question, I guess I need to have $||f(d)-f(c)|| \in \epsilon$ whenever $||d-c|| < \delta$, for $c,d \in [a,b]$. Then how do I show $|{g'(c)} - {{g(d)-g(c)} \over {d-c}}|$ = $||f(d)-f(c)||$.

Hints please!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just use the uniform continuity of $g'(x)$.

By Lagrange's mean value theorem, there exists $e$ between $c$ and $d$, s.t. $g'(e)=\frac{g(d)-g(c)}{d-c}$. Since $[a,b]$ is compact, $g'(x)$ is continuous and thus uniformly continuous in $[a,b]$. $|g'(c)-g'(e)|<\epsilon$ is just the consequence of uniform continuity.